# Elasticsearch count if more than one document with same value exists

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I want the count of documents if the value of a field is same in more than one documents. How can I write a DSL query to do so?

**Example:**

Let's say I have these documents:

```
{ _id:1, foo:1}
{ _id:2, foo:1}
{ _id:3, foo:3}
{ _id:4, foo:2}
{ _id:5, foo:3}
```

I want the count of documents if the same value of foo is found in more than one documents. Here, I want the count as 2.

**UPDATE**

After running the terms query as:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "counts": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "foo"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

I got this result:

```
'aggregations':{
    'counts':{
        'buckets':[
             {'doc_count': 221,'key': '10284'},
             {'doc_count': 71,'key': '6486'},
             {'doc_count': 71,'key': '7395'}
         ],
        'doc_count_error_upper_bound': 0,
        'sum_other_doc_count': 0
    }
}
```

I want another field as `total_count` which has the value 3 as there are 3 keys with doc_count more than 1. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't think you can do this out of the box with ES only. You basically need a bucket count after a `min_doc_count: 2` `terms` aggregation.

Comment: In ES 5 you will have this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19553 (for `bucket_selector` aggregation there will be a `_bucket_count` variable that can be used). Still to be seen if that variable can be used in other scripts as well.

Comment: Good point mentioning the new `_bucket_count` variable, @AndreiStefan

Comment: I'm using ES 4, so `_bucket_count` is not a possibility. I'll be simply counting the buckets with the client side to achieve my final goals.

Comment: ES 2.3.3, my fault!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a simple `terms` aggregation on the `foo` field like this:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "counts": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "foo"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

After running this, you'll get

- for key 1: doc_count 2
- for key 3: doc_count 2
- for key 1: doc_count 1

Comment: Is there a way by which I can simply get 2? I need to do this as I would be running this query with a date histogram to find the count of such documents on a daily basis and there can be tens of thousands of each key per day.

Comment: Can you run the query, and see the results you get, then explain what fields from those results you'd like to get. (update your question with that information)

Comment: Updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: In your client code, you could simply count the number of buckets, right?

Comment: That I can, but I was hoping if I could do that with elasticsearch as python is a slow language compared to Java and in a live environment the number of keys would be very high. If it is not possible with ES, I would be using python to achieve the final goal.

Comment: Be careful with statements such as "python is a slow language compared to the Java" :-) Try to simply do it on the client-side (e.g. `len(resp['aggregations']['counts']['buckets'])`) and see how it goes

Comment: I have used the terms aggregation and then manipulate the data as required by Python. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this out of the box with ES only. You basically need a bucket count after a `min_doc_count: 2` `terms` aggregation.

In ES 5 you will have this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19553 (for `bucket_selector` aggregation there will be a `_bucket_count` variable that can be used). Still to be seen if that variable can be used in other scripts as well.